# How to insert the output of a SQL Query into a temporary table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, temp-tables

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I want to perform the following operations using T-SQL:

1. Create a temporary table (let's call it `#temptable`).
2. Insert values from tables located in an existing database into
   `#temptable` using a `SELECT` statement.
3. Write a `SELECT` statement that will query the `#temptable`.

I have tried the following but it seems the syntax is not correct or perhaps what I am trying to do is not allowed.

```
USE MyDatabase

CREATE TABLE #temptable
GO

INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT  [Col A], [Col B], [Col C]

FROM MYLIST

WHERE [MONTH OF STAY] = '2018-03-01'

AND [Property] = 'ABC'

SELECT * FROM #temptable
```

How do I move forward with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [create temp table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql), you need to specify the columns and datatypes too. Temp table is created just like a persistant table.
However you can use `Select Into` statement, which will create the table automatically based on the given `Select` statement
Try This:

```
USE MyDatabase
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') Is Not null
    Drop Table #TempTable

SELECT  [Col A], [Col B], [Col C]
INTO #TempTable -- <<<<<
FROM MYLIST

WHERE [MONTH OF STAY] = '2018-03-01'

AND [Property] = 'ABC'

SELECT * FROM #temptable
```

In above code, you need to check if table with the given name is exists or not? If exists, then you will need to drop it, prior to execute the `Select Into`. Because `Select Into` will automatically create the table for you, and if table with same name exists, then you will get error.